# Next-Auth signIn with Credentials is not working in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm integrating next-auth package to my fresh Next.js project. I have followed all of the Next.js and next-auth documentations but not able to find a solution.

The issue I'm facing goes like this:
I want to Login to my Next.js app using Email & Password submitted to my API Server running on Laravel.
When submitting the login form I'm executing the below function.

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/client";

const loginHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
    });

    console.log("finished signIn call");
    console.log(result);
};
```

And code shown below is in my `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";

export default NextAuth({
    session: {
        jwt: true,
    },
    providers: [
        Providers.Credentials({
          async authorize(credentials) {
            axios
              .post("MY_LOGIN_API", {
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password,
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return true;
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                throw new Error('I will handle this later!');
              });
          },
        }),
    ],
});
```

But when try to login with correct/incorrect credentials, I get the below error in Google Chrome console log.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials? 401 (Unauthorized)
{error: "CredentialsSignin", status: 401, ok: false, url: null}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation (https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials#example)

```
async authorize(credentials, req) {
  // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
  const user = { id: 1, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }

  if (user) {
    // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
    return user
  } else {
    // If you return null or false then the credentials will be rejected
    return null
    // You can also Reject this callback with an Error or with a URL:
    // throw new Error('error message') // Redirect to error page
    // throw '/path/to/redirect'        // Redirect to a URL
  }
}
```

You are not currently returning a user or `null` from the `authorize` callback.

Comment: Can you explain why the status in the response from the next API call, always comes as 200 and ok value is also always true? This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5):

Answer posted by shanewwarren is correct, but here is more elaborated answer,

Using axios to solve this

```
 async authorize(credentials, req) {
        return axios
          .post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API}/auth/login`, {
            identifier: credentials.identifier,
            password: credentials.password,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response);
            throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
          }) || null;
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

add try/cath inside async authorize(credentials) {}
put some log there, in my case, I check the log and fixed the problem by using other node version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).